# Package R does not exist even when the package in the java files matches the one in the Manifest file

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, makefile

I'm a beginner with Android developpement and I don't use Android Studio but Atom.
I have this error when I try to compile my code :

```
gradle build
:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/home/sofian/Programmation/Web/phone-appli/src/main/java/fr/cavallones/phoneappli/MainActivity.java:8: error: cannot find sym
bol

import fr.cavallones.phoneappli.R;
                               ^
  symbol:   class R
  location: package fr.cavallones.phoneappli
/home/sofian/Programmation/Web/phone-appli/src/main/java/fr/cavallones/phoneappli/MainActivity.java:18: error: package R does
 not exist
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity);
                        ^
2 errors
```

The source code on github : https://github.com/Cavallones/phone-appli

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: You're a beginner and you don't use Android Studio but Atom? What's the point of doing that?

Comment: @sudo I'm not a beginner in code or stuff. I'm under Debian and just a beginner with android developpement. Plus, Android Studio needs at least 4GB of RAM to launch and I bearly have that much, so it's just awfull to use for me.

Comment: I'm just saying that it's a lot easier to use Android Studio than just a text editor, especially when you begin to develop Android apps.

Comment: @sudo Yeas, I clearly agree with you on that point ! But as I said, my computer cannot run Android Studio, it asks too much RAM and make the whole thing lagging..